# Move widgets in Scatter individually in Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, draggable, scatter

I'm trying to create a custom Widget of which i want to add multiple instances to a layout. These widgets should be draggable.

One way of getting the desired result is to use the [DragBehavior Mixin](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.drag.html), which I have already successfully implemented. Now I wanted to get the same result using a [Scatter](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scatter.html).

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter


class MyLabelWidget(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 1, 0, 0.25)
            self.background_rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        self.bind(pos=self.update)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.background_rect.pos = self.pos


class ScattererApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = 400, 400

        layout = FloatLayout()
        scatter = Scatter()

        widget_1 = MyLabelWidget(
            size_hint=(None, None),
            size=(100, 100),
            pos=(50, 50),
            text="Drag me",
        )
        widget_2 = MyLabelWidget(
            size_hint=(None, None),
            size=(100, 100),
            pos=(150, 150),
            text="Drag me, too",
        )

        layout.add_widget(scatter)
        scatter.add_widget(widget_1)
        scatter.add_widget(widget_2)

        return layout


ScattererApp().run()
```

But unfortunately, when I try to drag one widget, the position of all widgets change:

[image: Scatter implementation]

What I would like to have is to be able to drag the widgets individually, like I did with the `DragBehavior` implementation:

[image: DragBehavior implementation]

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class DragLabel(DragBehavior, Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.drag_rectangle = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        self.drag_timeout = 10000000
        self.drag_distance = 0

        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 1, 0, 0.25)
            self.background_rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        self.bind(pos=self.update)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.drag_rectangle = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        self.background_rect.pos = self.pos


class DraggerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = 400, 400
        layout = FloatLayout()

        widget_1 = DragLabel(
            size_hint=(None, None),
            size=(100, 100),
            pos=(50, 50),
            text="Drag me",
        )
        widget_2 = DragLabel(
            size_hint=(None, None),
            size=(100, 100),
            pos=(150, 150),
            text="Drag me, too",
        )

        layout.add_widget(widget_1)
        layout.add_widget(widget_2)

        return layout


DraggerApp().run()
```

It seems like my `update` callback method never gets called, although I [bound](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html) it on the position of the `MyLabelWidget` object, as described in the [Updating canvas instructions declared in Python](https://blog.kivy.org/2014/10/updating-canvas-instructions-declared-in-python/) article by Alexander Taylor:

```py
self.bind(pos=self.update)
```

Is there any way to achieve the desired effect without using the [Kv language](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I seemed to have used the Scatter class incorrectly. Each widget should be a scatter itself, not just added to a single scatter instance:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter


class MyLabelWidget(Scatter, Label):
    def __init__(self, bgcolor, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(*bgcolor)
            self.background_rect = Rectangle(
                pos_hint=(None, None),
                pos=self.pos,
                size_hint=(None, None),
                size=self.size,
            )


class Scatterer2App(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = 400, 400

        layout = FloatLayout()

        widget_1 = MyLabelWidget(
            size_hint=(None, None),
            size=(100, 100),
            pos=(50, 50),
            bgcolor=(1, 0, 0, 1),
            text="Drag me",
        )
        widget_2 = MyLabelWidget(
            size_hint=(None, None),
            size=(100, 100),
            pos=(150, 150),
            bgcolor=(0, 0, 1, 1),
            text="Drag me, too",
        )

        layout.add_widget(widget_1)
        layout.add_widget(widget_2)
        return layout


Scatterer2App().run()
```

But this results in the label and label background being positioned incorrectly:

[image: Scatterer2App]

To solve this problem, `MyLabelWidget` should not inherit from `Scatter`, but be added to a single `Scatter` instance:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyLabelWidget(Label):
    def __init__(self, bgcolor, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(*bgcolor)
            self.background_rect = Rectangle(size=self.size)


class MyScatterLabelWidget(Scatter):
    def __init__(self, bgcolor, text, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.label = MyLabelWidget(size=self.size, bgcolor=bgcolor, text=text)
        self.add_widget(self.label)


class Scatterer3App(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = 400, 400

        layout = FloatLayout()

        widget_1 = MyScatterLabelWidget(
            size_hint=(None, None),
            size=(100, 100),
            pos=(50, 50),
            bgcolor=(1, 0, 0, 1),
            text="Drag me",
        )
        widget_2 = MyScatterLabelWidget(
            size_hint=(None, None),
            size=(100, 100),
            pos=(150, 150),
            bgcolor=(0, 0, 1, 1),
            text="Drag me, too",
        )

        layout.add_widget(widget_1)
        layout.add_widget(widget_2)
        return layout


Scatterer3App().run()
```

[image: Scatterer3App]